# Numpy delete() is deleting different arrays with same elements from 2D array

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have a 2D numpy array like 
`B = [[1. 0.], [0. 1.], [3. 1.]]`
 and I want to delete `[0. 1.]`, but when I do:

```
B = np.delete(B, [0, 1], 0)
print(B)
```

both `[1. 0.], [0. 1.]` are deleted and I'm left with
`[[3. 1.]]`

thus I suppose `delete()` does not recognize different arrays with the same elements. What can I do?

Comment: Beware that `==` tests on floats is iffy.  It's more reliable when working with `int` dtype.  `isclose` is a better test for floats.

Answer (score 3):

You are asking delete() to remove first and second index by asking [0,1] as a parameter. This second arameter is the index from which you want to delete the value.
You should try:

```py
np.delete(B, 1, 0)
```

Comment: OK, so I misread the documentation. Sorry. What I'd like is to delete an array that I know a priori from the 2D array. For example, how can I delete the array [3. 1.] from the above 2D array just by informing it?

Comment: I don't know how to do that, but you could try first to find index of your value, and then call `delete()`.

Answer (score 0):

`np.delete(arr, idx)` deletes elements at the locations specified in `idx`

so

```py
B = np.delete(B, [0, 1], 0)
```

is deleting the elements at locations 0 and 1, which are the elements you mentioned, `[1. 0.]` and `[1. 0.]`

so to delete a specific array from a 2D array you need to know the index of the element you want to delete. You can do an ugly one liner like so

```py
B = np.delete(B, np.where((B==[0,1]).all(1)), 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Deleting by value:

```
B = np.array([[1., 0.], [0., 1.], [3., 1.]])
value = [3,1]
```

1) By keeping everything else (recommended):

```
B[(value!=B).any(1)]
# array([[1., 0.],
#        [0., 1.]])
```

2) Using `delete`:

```
np.delete(B,np.where((value==B).all(1)),0)
# array([[1., 0.],
#        [0., 1.]])
```